# Talend tREST http compression

Tags: java, talend

i enabled http compression on a tREST component but now the Main output is encoded.  is there a way to get the plain strings back?

[image: talend tREST compression]

"Content-Encoding: gzip"
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this that easily if it don't work out of the box.

The easiest way to discover if something works and how something works, is probably to take a look at the source of the component you're using.

In this case we take a look at tRest_begin.javajet:

You'll find the following passage:

```
...
com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client restClient_<%=cid%> = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(config_<%=cid%>);
com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource restResource_<%=cid%>;
...
```

https://github.com/Talend/tdi-studio-se/tree/master/main/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider/components/tREST/tRest_begin.javajet

So now we know, that talend uses the jersey.api.client for the tRest component. This library doesn't seem to interpret the Content-Encoding Header and automatically decompress the data. Instead you seem to be forced to use:
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/GZIPContentEncodingFilter.html

So whats left?

To solve your problem, you could get the tRest component and modify it the way it works and create a new component out of it, which delivers the functionality you need.

I also suggest you to read the following, which helps you to understand how components work and how you can create them yourself:

http://www.powerupbi.com/talend/componentCreation_1.html